# How to pass JSON array using JAVA component in Mule 4, as i am getting error if i pass JSON array

Tags: mulesoft, mule4

```
Cannot coerce Array { encoding: UTF-8, mediaType: application/java; charset=UTF-8, mimeType: application/java, raw: org.mule.weave.v2.model.structure.SeqArrayValue@38b1b5db, class: java.util.ArrayList } ([{I_PARTNER_ID: "CNLIGHT01" as String {class: "java.lang.String"},I_ACTION_CO...) to Object" evaluating expression: "payload
```

Comment: There are not enough details provided to understand the issue and the question lacks clarity. Kindly read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on how to improve your question. To begin, you should add the complete error message (seems truncated), the source code, the input or inputs and the flow that contains this component (in text XML). Avoid to use screenshots unless it is an UI issue.